# VS 2013 and Git Syncing - Error while copying content to a stream

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, azure-devops, team-explorer

I get an error while trying to push a new project to my VS Online Git repo.

I created a new repo in VS Online, cloned it to my local pc, and then copied my project files into the local repo via File Explorer. I've included all the files, added an ignore file and committed them.

When I try to Sync or just Push Unsynced Commits I get the following error:

```
An error occurred. Detailed message: An error was raised by libgit2. Category = Net (Error).
Error while copying content to a stream.
```

One small issue is that I am using a satellite internet connection - it's pretty quick but has high latency. Everything else in VS Team Explorer works fine though.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this same problem when attempting to push a new local repo up to a new TFS Git remote.  The repo had some large files and lots of history. The total size was just over 556 MB.  The solution was to use native Git from the command line. I assume this side steps LibGit2 completely.  I used the following command from the local repo location:

git push --all

Comment: Thanks for coming back - I think at least some of my problem was working on a satellite connection, where the latency is awful.

Answer (score 1):

I used git-gui to push the project. http://git-scm.com/docs/git-gui

It probably uses the same commands with the command tool behind the scenes, but saves you typing.